# Why does an iterator operator + return a copy?

Tags: c++, iterator

If you had an iterator `vector<int>::iterator i = vector.begin()`, `i++` moves the actual iterator down. But why does something like

`i = i + 3`

give you a new iterator three doors down?

Comment: What alternative are you expecting? `i + 3;` mutating `i` to advance by 3?

Comment: why do binary `operator+` return a copy? Because semantically, `A+B` should return a new object and leave the arguments unmodified.

Comment: To take the anology further, what happens if, for example, you said `2 + 3`? You don't change the `2` or `3`, but instead you take both arguments and create a result, `5`, while leaving `2` and `3` unchanged (because changing `2` and `3` makes no sense... you'd ruin the whole mathematical world if you somehow changed `2` or `3`). Similarly, if you replace `2` with an iterator or other variable, it makes sense to keep the logic the same and not change the iterator or variable, but instead to return a new instance that represents the result.

Answer (score 6):

To mimic the natural behaviour that one would expect from `+`. The same way that in:

```
int x = 0;
int y = x + 3;
```

The second line doesn't change `x`, it just evaluates to the value of 3. However, `x++` *would* modify `x`.

If you want to advance a generic iterator, you should use `std::advance(i, 3)` (it will do `i += 3` on a Random Access Iterator and `i++` three times on any other).

Answer (score 4):

When you use `operator+`, you don't expect either of the operands to be modified.  So that means a new object must be created.  Just like if you did this:

```
int a = 5;
int b = a + 3;
```

You would still expect a to be equal to 5.

Answer (score 1):

So that you can write:

```
j = i + 3;
```

If `operator+` didn't create a new copy, what *would* it do? Modify `i`?

Answer (score 1):

It is because `x + n` should **not** change the value of `x` irrespective of what `x` is, whether it is `int` or `iterator`. The idea is same.

However if you don't want to write this:

```
it = it + 3;
```

then you have an alternative, you could write this:

```
std::advance(it, 3);
```

Note that in case of some standard containers which do not support **random access iterator**<sup>1</sup>, you **cannot** write `it = it + 3`, but you **can** still write `std::advance(it,3)`. For example:

```
std::list<int>::iterator it = lst.begin();

it  = it + 3; //COMPILATION ERROR. `it` is not random access iterator

std::advance(it,3); //okay
```

So in such cases, `std::advance(it,3)` is the only way *(or else you've to write such functionality yourself)*.

<sup>1. Note that `std::vector<T>::iterator` is random access iterator, that is why you can write `it+3`.</sup>